# ARKit Model Rendering - Z-fighting / Flickering

Tags: 3d, rendering, augmented-reality, arkit, flicker

**The Problem**

I'm developing an Augmented Reality application in ARKit and want to render a large, complex 3D-model at a great distances, 100-1000 meters. The model consists of several layers of different materials with overlapping planes and planes located close to each other etc. I am having trouble with flickering. I assume this is because of Z-fighting. Are there any methods to work around this problem?

**Have tried**

I have tried changing the rendering order of the different nodes. Starting to render from "inside-out", results in much worse performance. Starting to render from "outside-in", doesn't improve the performance at all.

I have tried turning of litPerPixel, worse results.

I have tried rendering the model at 20 m distance with small effects of flickering / Z-fighting.

**Current work around**

Right now we are working around the problem by translating the model closer, like 20 meters, and scale it down accordingly. However, we aren't satisfied with the results and want to find a solution for great distances instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove shadows progressively as model moves away. Beware of lightning and shadows when models are far.